# When will the Retbleed mitigation for Focal/Bionic be released?

Tags: kernel, security, backport

[Retbleed](https://comsec.ethz.ch/research/microarch/retbleed/) was announced in July, and was subsequently fixed pretty quickly in Jammy. Ever since, Focal and Bionic are in "Needs Triage" state, at Ubuntu's [CVE-2022-29900](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-29900) tracking page.

What is the state of the Retbleed mitigation for Focal/Bionic? And more generally: For any given upstream kernel change, how can I track its integration back into older LTS releases (so I might know where to look in the future)?

Answer (score 2):

A fix was released for Focal in the form of the `linux-hwe-5.15` kernel.

In addition, very few people here will know what you're asking (unless they're part of the Ubuntu kernel team).

I would guess the  [kernel team mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/kernel-team) is the appropriate place to discuss these matters.